# AngularJs: ng-click not working for certain case

Tags: angularjs

There is clearly something fundamental but I can't search any other useful posts on this.

For first case, it worked as expected. When click on button B, I am getting 2. For second case, it is not working anymore when I changed the numbers to A&B. Please find the code as below.

**First Case**

```
<p>Click the button:</p>

<button ng-click="name = 1" ng_init="name=0">A</button>
<button ng-click="name = 2" ng_init="name=0">B</button>

<p>This is {{name}}.</p>
```

**Second Case**

```
<p>Click the button:</p>

<button ng-click="name = A" ng_init="name=0">A</button>
<button ng-click="name = B" ng_init="name=0">B</button>

<p>This is {{name}}.</p>
```

Comment: I guess it is not ng_init..... it is ng-init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name = A
```

assigns the value of `$scope.A` to `$scope.name`. I assume you don't have any property named `A` in the scope, so name is set to `undefined`. You probably want

```
name = 'A'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works after putting in the single quote.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are probably strings, so you should assign it as a string.

```
<button ng-click="name = 'A' " ng_init="name=0">A</button>
<button ng-click="name = 'B' " ng_init="name=0">B</button>
```

Hope it helps :)